# Android Slow Scrolling with the ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView that has some image Views. However, the scrolling is very slow and I do not understand what is the reason for the bad performance. Is there anything to do to speed up the scrolling ? 
or what can cause this problem ?

`

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <ImageView />

        <ImageView />

         <ImageView />

         <ImageView />

         <ImageView />

                <ImageView />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Besides the unnecessarily nested `RelativeLayout` there doesn't seem to be anything that would cause an issue. By "slow" do you mean it literally scrolls slowly or do you mean choppy and maybe problems with rendering when scrolling? How big are those images you are loading? If you are loading big images, maybe try reducing their file sizes?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the size of the images.
So if you have some performance issues with ScrollView and multiple ImageViews, pay attention to the size of your images! In my case I reduced them to approx. 20KB - 50KB each image.

Comment: i have 20 of images with 17-25 KB each image. then why its lagging?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very fluent in english but i will try to explain it to you !

you just have to try to change you scrollview position like this

```
 **<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <ImageView />

    <ImageView />

     <ImageView />

     <ImageView />

     <ImageView />

            <ImageView />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The more child views within child views you have the more taxing on the system , I don't get why would you use a `RelativeLayout` inside a parent `RelativeLayout`. you only posted a snipet but I see that you have to many child layouts.

You find more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

it should look like this , or replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` .

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Even If I remove all the RelativeLayouts, and I have just the ScrollView and inside one RelativeLayout it is still very slow.

Comment: why do you have them empty `ImageView` tags

Comment: I removed the code inside the ImageView  just for the example.